# Get chrome version from commandline in Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome, mac

In Ubuntu, using the command **google-chrome --product-version** I am able to get the chrome version. Is there any equivalent command for MacOS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Execute this:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version
```